# Program structure using asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, coroutine, python-asyncio

I currently have a program structured like this:

```
set_up_everthing()

while True:
    if new_client_ready():
        connect_new_client()

    for client in clients:
        if client.is_ready():
            get_input_from(client)

    update_program_state_based_on_input()

    for client in clients:
        if client.is_ready():
            send_output_to(client)

clean_up()
```

The network I/O currently uses sockets and select, but I want to rewrite it to use the asyncio library. I think I understand how to make a simple asyncio program, the idea seems to be that when you want to do some I/O, you `yield from` a function that does it, so when the main loop gets a new client, it does `yield from accept_client()`, and when that client receives information it does `yield from read_information()`, and so on. However, I can't work out how to combine this with other parts of the program.

Comment: here's [a simple but complete port forwarder implementation using `asyncio`](http://pastebin.com/g08YaJyz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your snippet roughly describes how asyncio works itself.

Please take a look on [asyncio example](https://code.google.com/p/tulip/source/browse/examples/echo_server_tulip.py) for how to **use** asyncio:

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def echo_server():
    yield from asyncio.start_server(handle_connection, 'localhost', 8000)

@asyncio.coroutine
def handle_connection(reader, writer):
    while True:
        data = yield from reader.read(8192)
        if not data:
            break
        writer.write(data)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(echo_server())
try:
    loop.run_forever()
finally:
    loop.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

The `asyncio` module has two levels of APIs: The **low-level** [transports & protocols API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html) and the **high-level** [streams API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html). They are like different frameworks. Depending on the API level you are using, your program structure may differ dramatically.

To prevent yourself from going crazy, normally you don't want to mix these two levels of APIs.

The two levels differ in that **you receive data in different ways**. The low-level API provides an event-driven interface, your program responds to incoming events by implementing callbacks - **The framwork calls your code**. The high-level API have a nicer look, in that it provides readers & writers, and **your code calls the framework**.

The examples in `asyncio` docs should be easy enough to follow.

Comment: Thank you!  A very helpful answer, expressed simply and concisely.

Comment: The stream and protocol styles aren't *that* different. The key if you use protocols is that you may need to make an asynchronous request while handling incoming data, so you have to `create_task` so that your data handling code can be a coroutine. You also have to know how to wake up a suspended task when data is ready, e.g. because your remote peer answered a request.